# Prove that $\lim_{x\to -1^-} \frac{1}{x+1}=-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$.

We have to $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -1^-} \dfrac{1}{x+1}=-\infty \Leftrightarrow \forall M>0, \exists \delta>0 \text{ such that } 0<-1-x<\delta \text{ and } x\in D_f \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{x+1}<-M$

Trying to conjecture the $\delta$:

1. We want to show that $\dfrac{1}{x+1}<-M$. Organizing this inequality, we have to $\dfrac{1}{-1-x}>M$.
2. By hypothesis, we should have $-1-x<\delta$. So $-1-x<\delta \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{-1-x}>\dfrac{1}{\delta}$.
3. Comparing 1. and 2. consider $M=\dfrac{1}{\delta}$ so $\delta=\dfrac{1}{M}$.

Proof. Given $M>0$. Consider $\delta=\dfrac{1}{M}$, so

$-1-x<\dfrac{1}{M} \Leftrightarrow x+1>-\dfrac{1}{M} \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{x+1}<-M$ $\qquad\square$

This is my attempt, could someone help me to improve?

Sorry for the English mistakes, if possible, also adjust to the most coherent terms.

Comment: Do you mean $$\lim_{x\to \color{red}{-}1^-} \frac{1}{x+1}~?$$

Comment: Yes. In that case, I will update my attempt. Thanks.

Comment: $1^- \equiv 1-h$ where h →0 ....so the previous limit before edit should be 2 without a doubt

Comment: Updated. Is this proof good?